# Nesting VLOOKUPs if the result is #N/A

Tags: vlookup

I'm doing a VLOOKUP but some of the values can't be found in my range and returns #N/A.  To be expected but if that happens I want to do another VLOOKUP to another range.  I can't figure out how to combine the two formulae as an IF/IFERROR wants to enter a text value and the original VLOOKUP as a logical test won't be TRUE or FALSE.

The only solution I can think of is manual, ie. do one VLOOKUP then filter on the #N/A and manually apply the alternative VLOOKUP to only those cells but I'd rather have a consistent formula in all cells.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can test for the first VLOOKUP returning #N/A using the `IF` and `ISNA` functions, and then either select from one table or the other.

This formula checks if there is a result from the first table and if not, uses the VLOOKUP result from Table2, or if the first table had a match then it uses that VLOOKUP.

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP([@Column1],Table1, 2, FALSE)), VLOOKUP([@Column1], Table2, 2, FALSE), VLOOKUP([@Column1], Table1, 2, FALSE))
```

[image: Sample data using the above formula]

Comment: Hi Scott, Great, thank you.  I hadn't come across the ISNA function before.  Just what I needed!